# Successive phantomjs calls fail

Tags: php, phantomjs

I use exec() to make multiple successive calls to phantomjs from php but only first call gets executed, second call gets stuck and runs for ever. I have `phantom.exit(1);` in script. There is one phantomjs instance in task manager, and netbeans debugger is paused for ever.

```
    public static function render_tweet($tweet_url)
    {
        $selector = "[class='permalink-inner permalink-tweet-container']";
        $file = storage_path('temp\tweet1.png');  
        $script = app_path('MyApp\render_element_procedure.js');
        $phantom = base_path('bin\phantomjs.exe');


        $exec_str = sprintf('"%s" "%s" "%s" "%s" "%s"', $phantom, $script, $tweet_url, $selector, $file);
        $resp = exec($exec_str);
        return $file;
    }
```

Comment: Just a note, `phantom.exit(1)` means the job has failed. Also, if you do `$resp = exec($exec_str)` you'll only get [the last line](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) of script's output.

Comment: Does PhantomJS script work if run from the shell?

Comment: I found that `$selector` isn't always present on pages i try to screenshot, then it runs forever. What function to use to get full output instead exec()?

Maybe implement phantom.onError and page.onError handlers?

Comment: Please add PhantomJS script to the question so we can tune it. To get full output from `exec` please read how to use it on php.net: http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php